# Redirect 301 Dynamic URLs htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I Have a rule in my htaccess as below

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /detail_new?
location=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]
```

And it is working pretty fine as when i type URL as `http://example.com/location/id/name`

But when i type `http://example.com/detail_new.php?location=Panchkula&id=123&name=ABC` then also page opens up.

But here i want that `http://example.com/detail_new.php?location=XYZ&id=123&name=ABC` should always be redirected to `http://example.com/location/id/name`

I Handeled in PHP as below

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 if ((false !== strpos($url,'detail_new')) {
   $rebuilt_url = "http://example.com/location/id/name";
   header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: {$rebuilt_url}") ;  // redirect to this url
}
```

How can i do same in htaccess please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this rule to redirect actual URL to pretty one **before your earlier rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+detail_new\?location=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /detail_new?location=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Does it mean that `http://example.com/detail_new?location=A&id=B&name=C` shall be converted to `http://example.com/A/B/C` with above rewrite rule? but when i enter `http://example.com/detail_new?location=A&id=B&name=C` then it remain as it is :(

Comment: Ah there was a typo in my rule. It is fixed now, try again.